# When is a group the same as its profinite completion

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, profinite-groups

I'm working with the inner automorphism group of profinite quandles. A question I have yet to resolve is whether or not the inner automorphism group of a profinite quandle is necessarily profinite, or what sufficient conditions for this to occur are. For this reason, I'm interested about the relation between a group and its profinite completion.

Let $G$ be a group. We consider its profinite completion $\hat{G}$ and the question of whether or not $G\cong\hat{G}$. Clearly $G$ is dense in $\hat{G}$, so if $G$ is closed in $\hat{G}$, then $G\cong\hat{G}$. Is there another result characterizing when $G\cong\hat{G}$? If $G\not\cong\hat{G}$, then what is a natural way to go about finding an element of $\hat{G}$ that does not belong to $G$?

Comment: Such a profinite group is called strongly complete.  Nikolov and Segal showed a topologically finitely generated profinite group is strongly complete using the classification of finite simple groups among other things.  It’s a hard result.  Of course your condition is the same as all finite index subgroups being open.

Comment: Already the injectivity of $G\to\hat{G}$ means that $G$ is residually finite. In general it is a bit confusing to say "$G$ is dense in $\hat{G}$" when it's not even embedded.